Is it possible to use Spark DataFrameWriterV2 with external data warehouses like BigQuery
I found that DataFrameWriterV2 interface has very useful methods like overwriting data based on some columns.
But, I cannot find any examples of using it. So, I wonder, is it possible to use it to write data into BigQuery?
spark-bigquery-connector documentation tells nothing about it, but changelog has mentioned that this interface is implemented - see.
I've tried exporting data into BQ using this interface, but it gives an error like table does not exist or REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT is only supported with v2 tables.
